# Tmux does not work

Tags: tmux

I created many sessions in tmux and closed them all with one comand:
    pkill -f tmux

Unfortunately, now when I create new session via 
    tmux new -s alex
And get the following error:

> sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force

Tell me please how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you have `TMUX` in your environment variables?  Do you have any instances of `tmux` running (`ps -ef | grep tmux`)?

Comment: type `unset TMUX` and then run tmux. make sure you ain't start tmux from within tmux

Answer (score 0):

This message indicates that you are still in a session attach.

For example, you can check:

```
salio@salios ~ % tmux ls     
1: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 13 16:38:10 2023)
3: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 13 21:12:34 2023) (attached)
4: 1 windows (created Fri Jan 13 22:49:13 2023)
6: 2 windows (created Fri Jan 13 23:05:50 2023)
```

I am currently attached to session 3

If I run the following command, I get an error:

```
tmux attach-session -t <Favorite session>
```

> sessions should be nested with care, unset $TMUX to force

So, first of this session, dis-attach with the command ‍`Ctrl+b`+`d`
Now use the following command:

```
tmux attach-session -t <Favorite session>
```